# What netbooks will a PixelQi 10.1" 1280x800 epaper display work with?

Tags: display, netbook

How, without buying the netbook in question, can I determine whether a netbook will be compatible with aftermarket installation of a 10.1" 1280x800 (not the usual 1024x600 which can have the same diagonal size) PixelQi epaper display?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at the specification of the netbook in question. In most cases you will get one online. Relevant part is the graphics chip and the maximum amount of video RAM. From my experience it was never a problem, but one can't tell for every device.